# IP_PKTINFO socket option not working

Tags: c, linux, sockets, vlan

I have been banging my head on this one for a few weeks now and am finally submitting to the fact that I just can't figure it out.  I have also been working with networking engineers on my team to no avail.  My problem is as follows:

I am working on an application that does pretty straight forward UDP group joins on multiple vlans (each vlan is exposed as its own virtual interface, the NIC in this case is a SolarFlare if that is relevant).  All of these joins happen on a single socket (where the messages are de-duplicated based on payload sequence numbers).  Prior to doing the IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP I am setting socket options like this:

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, &yes, sizeof yes)
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &yes, sizeof(yes))
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, PACKET_AUXDATA, &yes, sizeof(yes))
```

I need to get at either the interface index via IP_PKTINFO or the vlan id via PACKET_AUXDATA in order to gather statistics downstream. Now, everything initializes without error and I am able to process UDP payloads without issue.  Where I run into trouble is when I attempt to access the ancillary / control messages requested above as demonstrated with the simple debug logging:

```
for (cmsgptr = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
    cmsgptr != NULL;
    cmsgptr = CMSG_NXTHDR(&msg, cmsgptr)) {
    printf("Control Message: cmsg_level: %d, cmsg_type %d\n", cmsgptr->cmsg_level, cmsgptr->cmsg_type);
}
```

For every packet received, this only outputs:

```
Control Message: cmsg_level: 1, cmsg_type 29
```

For reference, SOL_SOCKET=1 and SO_TIMESTAMP=29.   So, although I am requesting 3 different control message types, only the timestamping is being populated.  This behavior is independent of whether I am joining a single UDP group on a single interface or multiple groups on multiple interfaces.

One solution would be to rewrite the application to put each interface on its own socket, and then funnel everything into a queue, but in my experience the context switching kills the performance of the app.  According to the manual page ip(7) IP_PKTINFO has been available since Linux kernel 2.2.  I am running Ubuntu 14.04.4 which uses kernel 3.13.0-24-generic.

Any help, insight or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark guesses

1) You need to reset `yes` back to 1 after each successful call to `setsockopt`. The docs imply this isn't needed, but it's what I would do.

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, &yes, sizeof(yes));

yes = 1;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_PKTINFO, &yes, sizeof(yes));

yes = 1;
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, PACKET_AUXDATA, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

2) Are you checking the return value of setsockopt to see if those calls are correctly succeeding.  It's not clear if you've validated they are returning "0" for success or "-1" for error.  You should print out the return code for each call.

3) You aren't showing your `recvmsg` code which is what you presumably using to get the extra info.  But it's possible the `struct msghdr` is not initialized correctly.  Specifically is your buffer big enough to get all the control data?  Here's how I do it in my code:

```
struct iovec vec;
ssize_t ret;

const size_t CONTROL_DATA_SIZE = 1000;  // THIS NEEDS TO BE BIG ENOUGH.
char controldata[CONTROL_DATA_SIZE]; 
struct msghdr hdr = {};
sockaddr_storage addrRemote = {};

vec.iov_base = buf;
vec.iov_len = len;

hdr.msg_name = &addrRemote;
hdr.msg_namelen = sizeof(addrRemote);
hdr.msg_iov = &vec;
hdr.msg_iovlen = 1;
hdr.msg_control = controldata;
hdr.msg_controllen = CONTROL_DATA_SIZE;

ret = ::recvmsg(sockfd, &hdr, flags);
```